# Magento - Upload file in contact form

Tags: forms, magento, file-upload, contact-form

I have to create a new field in contact form to upload file.

I followed tuts and this is what i did :

in form.phtml :

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then i added the field in the contact form :

```
<li>
<label for="attachment"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Attachment') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
    <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" type="hidden" value="2000000" />
    <input name="attachment" id="attachment" class="input-text" type="file" />
</div>
```

I modified the IndexController.php in : /www/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers as :

```
<?php
/**
 * Contacts index controller
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Contacts
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT  = 'contacts/email/recipient_email';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER     = 'contacts/email/sender_email_identity';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE   = 'contacts/email/email_template';
    const XML_PATH_ENABLED          = 'contacts/contacts/enabled';

    public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();

        if( !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_ENABLED) ) {
            $this->norouteAction();
        }
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')
            ->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') );

        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function postAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ( $post ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($post);

                $error = false;

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }
                /**************************************************************/
                $fileName = '';
                if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name']) && $_FILES['attachment']['name'] != '') {
                    try {
                        $fileName       = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
                        $fileExt        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, ".") ,1));
                        $fileNamewoe    = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
                        $fileName       = preg_replace('/\s+', '', $fileNamewoe) . time() . '.' . $fileExt;

                        $uploader       = new Varien_File_Uploader('attachment');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc', 'docx','pdf'));
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'contacts';
                        if(!is_dir($path)){
                            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                        }
                        $uploader->save($path . DS, $fileName );

                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $error = true;
                    }
                }
                /**************************************************************//**************************************************************/
                $fileName = '';
                if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name']) && $_FILES['attachment']['name'] != '') {
                    try {
                        $fileName       = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
                        $fileExt        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, ".") ,1));
                        $fileNamewoe    = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
                        $fileName       = preg_replace('/\s+', '', $fileNamewoe) . time() . '.' . $fileExt;

                        $uploader       = new Varien_File_Uploader('attachment');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc', 'docx','pdf', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'gif'));
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'contacts';
                        if(!is_dir($path)){
                            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                        }
                        $uploader->save($path . DS, $fileName );

                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $error = true;
                    }
                }
                /**************************************************************/

                if ($error) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                /**************************************************************/
                //sending file as attachment
                $attachmentFilePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). DS . 'contacts' . DS . $fileName;
                if(file_exists($attachmentFilePath)){
                    $fileContents = file_get_contents($attachmentFilePath);
                    $attachment   = $mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment($fileContents);
                    $attachment->filename = $fileName;
                }
                /**************************************************************/
                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }

}
```

I created a `contacts` directory in `medias` with 777 rights

The contact form is correctly shown in my page, i can choose a file, but it isnt uploaded. In `medias/contacts/` no file, and in my email i have a attached file called `noname`
Impossible to use it. Im sure i did something wrong but i cant find what exactly is wrong.

Im not a pro Magento admin, so if you can explain me in details that will be cool :)

Thanks all

Comment: In the code you can see a part written twice , it was a mistake of copy/paste i changed it in original file ;)

Answer (score 3):

i have tried recreating your scenario in my local installation and changed your contoller file uploader code with one of my working modules.

```
/**************************************************************/
            $fileName = '';
            if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name']) && $_FILES['attachment']['name'] != '') {
                try {           

                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('attachment');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc', 'docx','pdf'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'contacts' . DS ;
                    if(!is_dir($path)){
                        mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                    }
                    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['attachment']['contacts'] );             
                    $newFilename = $uploader->getUploadedFileName();


                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $error = true;
                }
            }
            /**************************************************************/
```

This is working 100% correctly i have tested this for pdf also.

Please try changing once.

Comment: Thank you for your answer skv. I tried to paste your attachement part code in my indexcontroller, and my upload still not work. I receive the mail with a attachement called "noname" 0 bits ...

Comment: klipse, try exiting the code and check if any method giving error.. for ex : check echo $newFilename; die(); after save method... it should be working fine.. as on my local

Comment: I checked with the echo $newFilename; die(); jsut below $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['attachment']['contacts'] );

Comment: The file is correctly uploaded in the directory. I receive a white blank screen.

Comment: if i exit the code after $newFilename = $uploader->getUploadedFileName(); the upload failed...

Comment: the white screen is b'coz of die you have written... so is the file uploading now ?

Comment: I fixed the issue. Reading again and again the code, checking with print_r and die(). Now i can send a file in the email with the form.

Comment: is this line is correct  $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['attachment']['contacts'] ); ?

Comment: ['contacts'] should be an undefined index, use tmp_name

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if(file_exists($attachmentFilePath)){
```

With this

```
if(file_exists($attachmentFilePath) && is_file($attachmentFilePath)){
```

Because file_exists results to TRUE if the file OR the directory exists. My email being sent out would send a blank "Mail Attachment" file because the file upload input on my contact form was optional.